# "Undefined symbol" errors when trying to test iOS with multiple local SPM dependencies

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xctest, swift-package-manager

I'm currently in the process of refactoring my iOS codebase and am splitting out a number of Framework targets that my app depends on as multiple local SPM packages under a "Packages" directory. Each of these local SPM packages, in turn, depends on a number of external SPM libraries.

I've statically linked each target of these local packages under the "Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content" of my main iOS app, and my app compiles perfectly fine. However, when trying to run my unit tests, the app fails with an error message similar to the following:

```
        Command CompileSwiftSources failed with a nonzero exit code
        Undefined symbol: ___llvm_profile_runtime
        Testing cancelled because the build failed.
```

I removed the faulty dependency and tried again, but then received more similar errors (with different undefined symbols), for my other dependencies. Each dependency this error occurs on is an external SPM dependency of one of my local SPM packages.

I've disabled Code Coverage in my test scheme, as I read that that can sometimes cause this error, but I'm still receiving it.

Any idea why? Has anyone else faced a similar issue? Happy to provide any more resources or info that can help debug.

Comment: How are the tests set up? Are they part of any package or part of a dedicated target? Do you use an `xctestplan`? Have you set a `Host Application`? The latter might help.